# How to fix blank images when I click search I get image boxes but It wont show the image(s)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have php code that allows you to upload an image to a database, and the image shows once uploaded, my problem is that when I search the file name of the image, I only get a blank image block

Should I find some other code?

Or is there something wrong with the way I have written my code?

I tried indenting the first two, but it still wouldn't work and i would get more errors saying 'Unexpected Indent' or

Get.php:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>file_name</th>
 <th>uploaded_on</th>
 <th>status</th>
</tr>
<?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","phpmyadmin","c0d1ng","createimage");
  $set = $_POST['search'];
if($set) {
   $show = "SELECT * FROM images where file_name='$set'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$show);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo  "<tr>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['file_name'];
     echo  "</td>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['uploaded_on'];
     echo   "</td>";
     echo   "<td>";       
     echo $rows['status'];
     echo   "</td>";

  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" width='350' height='300' alt=""/>
<?php }
  } else { ?>
       <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php  } ?>   


</table>
```

Upload.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once 'lendex.php';

    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){

            $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){

                    $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW()),";
                }else{
                    $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
                }
            }else{
                $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }

        if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
            $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL,',');

            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
            if($insert){
                $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.$errorUpload:'';
                $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.$errorUploadType:'';
                $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType;
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg;
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }


}
?>
```

search_pages.php

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>file_name</th>
 <th>uploaded_on</th>
 <th>status</th>
</tr>
<?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","phpmyadmin","c0d1ng","createimage");
  $set = $_POST['search'];
if($set) {
   $show = "SELECT * FROM images where file_name='$set'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$show);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo  "<tr>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['file_name'];
     echo  "</td>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['uploaded_on'];
     echo   "</td>";
     echo   "<td>";       
     echo $rows['status'];
     echo   "</td>";

  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" width='350' height='300' alt=""/>
<?php }
  } else { ?>
       <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php  } ?>   


</table>
```

My actual results are blank image boxes

Comment: `<?php echo $imageURL; ?>`, where does `$imageURL` come from?

Comment: PHP gave you an error message saying "Unexpected Indent"?  Are you *sure* about that?  Indentation/whitespace doesn't matter to PHP.

Comment: Look at the source in your browser to see what is populated in the src. That's the important part of this question.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks! _Never ever_ put unescaped user data in your queries like that. Read up on using [parameterized prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: What happens if a sql injection has taken place?

Comment: @NajmaMuhammad: If malicious, whatever the user wants to happen.  If accidental, usually a syntax error.

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid. You're currently putting the `img`-tag directly after a closing `</td>`. The only thing that can be directly after a `</td>` is `<td>` or `</tr>` (which you are completely missing btw),

Comment: Your HTML code is badly malformed. Maybe the browser is confused and had a heart attack (no I'm not joking).

Comment: You can read more about SQL injections here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: $imageURL does not have an initialization. Should I initialize it?

Comment: @NajmaMuhammad: If you want your variable to have a value then you would need to put a value in it.  Otherwise what would you expect that variable to output and why?

Comment: I assumed it to have an output because when I did not initialize the variable it still worked, was I wrong to assume so?